# How to refresh a page and content in Windows8 application

Tags: c#, windows-8, page-refresh

So I have a windows 8 app, in which I set some data to the defaultViewModel. My question is, after the page is created, and I add something to the data, how do I refresh the page and display the changes made?

```
    protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
    {            
        //inital load
        var DataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups((String)navigationParameter);
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = DataGroups;           
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //when the page is navigated back to after making changes to sampledatasource
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        this.DefaultViewModel.Clear();
        var DataGroups = SampleDataSource.GetGroups("AllGroups");
        this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = DataGroups;           
    }
```

The changes I make are not reflected untill the next time I open the application and the page is reloaded.
Here is the view model:

```
    protected IObservableMap<String, Object> DefaultViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(DefaultViewModelProperty) as IObservableMap<String, Object>;
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(DefaultViewModelProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

This is the list view I would like to update:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="itemListView"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    TabIndex="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    Margin="0,-10,0,0"
    Padding="10,0,0,60"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard80ItemTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"/>
```

Bound to this:

```
<CollectionViewSource
    x:Name="itemsViewSource"
    Source="{Binding Items}"
    d:Source="{Binding AllGroups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

msdn function:

```
public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Comment: After some digging around INotifyPropertyChanged has come up a lot as an interface but I have no idea how to use it in this instance... Not sure if it is the right one or not either.

Comment: Alright, after some more digging around I found some Microsoft documentation on data binding... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758320 Still not sure how to apply it to the code though.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the BindableBase class code which is usually created as in the Common folder of your Windows 8 Store project if you use the templates (except the Blank App template). If your start point is a Blank App template, you can create a new BasicPage, and Visual Studio will ask if you would like to include the common files.

Basically, the idea goes like so:

1. You implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface
2. Create a custom PropertyChanged event
3. At the point after you set a new value for the property, you call this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName) which will emit the change event for that property. The control will then be notified that the property has changed, and will be automatically updated with the new value.

Comment: Ok for #1, where do I implement the  INotifyPropertyChanged interface? BindableBase already has that implemented and the places where I change the data are sealed classes, not sure I am following. I have updated main post to reflect the list view I would like to update.

Comment: Looking at your code, your ListView seems to be bound to a static resource called itemsViewSource. How is this defined? Also, you don't necessarily have to use BindableBase. You can make your sealed classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and follow the same logic. All you have to do is raise the PropertyChanged event after you make any changes to the view model.

Comment: itemsViewSource is just bound to a collectionViewSource (xaml) which is intern bound to DefaultViewModel["Items"], So i suppose I need to make the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for that? if so, should I be passing in NotifyPropertyChanged(DefaultViewModel["Items"]); ? or that as a string because the msdn has a function that passes a string (see main post)

Comment: You should pass in the actual name of the property. In your case, that would be "DefaultViewModel".

Comment: Alright well, I implemented this: public sealed partial class ItemsPage : My_App.Common.LayoutAwarePage, INotifyPropertyChanged and then called NotifyPropertyChanged("DefaultViewModel"); when it was navigated back to after changes but still no update...

Comment: I suppose my issues are all on INotifyPropertyChanged, after creating a blank project, I used msdn's code but I still couldn't get the event to trigger as public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; is null all the time.... used the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

```
public bool Reload()
{
    if (!this.Frame.BackStack.Any())
        return false;
    var current = this.Frame.BackStack.First();
    this.Frame.BackStack.Remove(current);
    return this.Frame.Navigate(current.SourcePageType, current.Parameter);
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Good to see you here too :)